# $ not defined error in jquery

Tags: jquery

```
<script type= "text/javascript"
        src = "jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>

<script type= "text/javascript">


   //<!CDATA[[

$(init);

function init() {
 $("#heading").load("head.html");
 $("#menu").load("menu.html");
 $("#content1").load("story.html");
 $("#content2").load("story2.html");
 $("#footer").load("footer.html");
};

  //]]>

</script>
```

Comment: Don't you have to use the document.ready function?

Comment: Where are you including jquery in your above snippet?

Comment: I believe one can initiate with $(), no need to use document.ready with jquery

Comment: I don't think so. The DOM is not ready when your script is run

Comment: @Oskar `$(handler)` is synonymous with `$(document).ready(handler)`

Answer (score 7):

For some reason jQuery is not loading.

Check your path is it really `src = "jquery-1.4.2.min.js"` ? or could it be: `src = "jquery/1.4.2.min.js"`?

Make sure your jQuery is being loaded. Go to the source page and make sure you can read it. To debug use the full URL of the source instead of just a relative path. Then if that works, change it to a relative path and see if it still works.

---

Your first `<script>` tag is malformed:

**This is malformed:**

```
<script type= "text/javascript"
        src = "jquery-1.4.2.min.js"</script>
```

**It should read:**

```
<script type= "text/javascript"
        src = "jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
```

(note the `>` right before the `</`)

A clue to the presence of this type of problem is often the lack of syntax highlighting in your IDE or editor. In fact note the difference in the Stack Overflow syntax highlighting between the two code snippets above.

---

Also **[CDATA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CDATA)** should be

```
//<![CDATA[
```

and not:

```
//<!CDATA[[
```

Comment: fixed but still says $ is not defined

Comment: @user 449914 - Check that the jquery is being loaded... try putting in the full url as the source after going to that url to make sure the file is actually there.

Comment: @user449914 - It **should** be loading, but it's not **actually** loading. Initially using the full URL helps you debug. Can you see the jQuery code page by navigating there with your browser?

Comment: dumb ass error...jquery file was in a different folder!! sorry and thanks!

Comment: @user44914 - You're welcome ;) Happens to everyone. It's just a game of patience. Don't forget to accept my answer if it solved your problem. (Green check mark below the vote count).

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you reference your jQuery.js file correctly, Test by adding an alert('HIT!'); in you jQuery file if you are unsure.

Once you have that sorted, do the following:

```
<script type= "text/javascript">

$(function(){
 $("#heading").load("head.html");
 $("#menu").load("menu.html");
 $("#content1").load("story.html");
 $("#content2").load("story2.html");
 $("#footer").load("footer.html");});

</script>
```

OR if you want to use your function,

```
function init() {
 $("#heading").load("head.html");
 $("#menu").load("menu.html");
 $("#content1").load("story.html");
 $("#content2").load("story2.html");
 $("#footer").load("footer.html");
};
```

And call the init() just before the closing body tag.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you don't use [jQuery.noConflict()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/), this removes the `$` alias to avoid conflicts with other JavaScript libraries.